# Parallel with SwitchPoint sometimes no connection error on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

Using ruby parallel and switch_point gems in a Rails application:

- https://github.com/grosser/parallel
- https://github.com/eagletmt/switch_point

```
# maybe helps: explicitly use connection pool
Parallel.each(User.all.each_slice(8).to_a) do |users|
  Parallel.each(users, in_threads: 8) do |user|
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      user.update_attribute(:some_attribute, some_value)
    end
  end
end
```

SwitchPoint config file like:

```
SwitchPoint.configure do |config|
  config.define_switch_point :blog_db,
    readonly: :"#{Rails.env}_blog_db_slave",
    writable: :"#{Rails.env}_blog_db_master"

  config.auto_writable = true
end
```

app/models/application.rb

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  use_switch_point :blog_db
end
```

Sometimes got this error:

```
error: No connection pool with 'SwitchPoint::Proxy::BlogDBReadonly' found.
```

Have no idea why.

Comment: what you have given for `use_switch_point :` in your model?

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan Added model source.

Comment: can u try changing all blog_db to blog or blogdb ? please add you database.yml too